# NullPointerException when creating new String

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

> **SOLUTION**
>
> I was adding a **new instance** of `A` to the list: `aList.add( new A() )`, whose `name` property is of course null, **instead of adding the actual initialized instance**. Sorry for the dumb question.

---

I have this `A` class of `ProjectA` which overrides its `toString` method to return a clone of its `name` property, like this:

```
public class A {
    private String name;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new String(name);
    }
}
```

I then export this library to a jar and import it into `ProjectB` and when I call `a.toString()` I get a `NullPointerException` that says there is an error exactly on the return line: `return new String(name);`.

However, if I put it like this:

```
public class A {
    private String name;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I don't get any exception but the `String` returned is `null`.

I built the jar (`ProjectA`) using Eclipse and imported it into ADT (`ProjectB` - Eclipse too).

**NOTE:**

I omitted the getters/setters intentionally for the sake of simplicity, but they're in there in the original code and I'm pretty sure I set the `name` property way before calling the `toString()` method. In fact, if I call the `getName()` method, the name is returned perfectly fine, but I'm using lists and I need the `toString()` method.

This is the part of the code where the `List` of `A` objects is created (`ProjectA` too):

```
ArrayList<A> aList = new ArrayList<Categoria>();
for (int i = 0; i < random.nextInt(3)+1; i++) {
    A a = new A();
    a.setId(0);
    a.setName("Test name");
    a.setDescription("Test desc.");
    aList.add(a);

    Log.d("app", "Created object A: "+a.getName()); // The name is displayed OK here
}
aList.trimToSize();
```

And this is the exact part of the code where the `toString()` method is called (`ProjectA`):

```
new ArrayAdapter<A>(
    actionBar.getThemedContext(),
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    android.R.id.text1, 
    DataAccess.getAList() // The ArrayAdapter class calls the toString method to populate a list
)
```

As you could see, I in fact verify the content of the `name` property via the `getName()` method and it is okay. I have to mention that the first approach (the on which uses `new String(name)`, without an finals nor null checks) worked flawlessly on another project.

This is the (relevant part of the) `DataAccess` class:

```
public final class DataAccess {
    private static final Data data;
    public static Arrayist<A> getAList() {
        return this.data.getAList();
    }
}
```

Comment: so obviously name is null?

Comment: Why do you expect `name` to be anything else than null? It's private, there's no setter -> there's no other possibility.

Comment: I omitted the setters/getters but I'm sure the name property is set before I try to call the `toString()` method.

Comment: The stack trace should show the calling point in the code, maybe the name is not yet set - what else?

Comment: I edited my post and added code snippets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you invoke `new String(name);`  it invokes the overloaded parameterized constructor of String shown below :

```
   public String(String original) {
    int size = original.count;

    ........ 
    .........
   }
```

As you can see the first line in the code tries to compute the length of the String passed to the constructor. Since in your case the String is `null` invoking the member variable count on that null reference throws NullPointerException.

Note : In the code where you create AList, i dont see you adding the object to the list i.e. `AList.add(a);` is missing

Comment: Can you post the code where you are trying to call toString()

Comment: @Braj   If you try to use something like String str = new String(null);  then the compiler will complain

Comment: Can you post this function DataAccess.getAList()

Comment: It just returns the `ArrayList<A> aList` object that is a property of the `Data` class, which is a property of the `DataAccess` class.

Comment: In the code where you create AList, i dont see you adding the object to the list. AList.add(a) is missing

Comment: What an idiot. I actually add an object to the list but instead of adding the `a` object I just kept adding a `new A()` object. Sorry, it's a pretty lenghty class and I got that part missing. Thank you and thank you everyone!

Comment: I didn't mark it before because it wasn't the proposed answer the solution to my problem, just that comment. Maybe you could please edit your answer and point out what was the real issue and how it was solved. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

In java `new String(null)` results into `NullPointerException`.

---

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    if(name!=null){
        return name;
    }else{
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: I omitted the getters and setters in the example (for the sake of simplicity) but I'm sure I set the `name` property way before calling the `toString()` method.

Comment: Make it `final` for 100% surety.

Comment: or put a `null` check in `toString()` method.

Comment: I'll try the `final` modifier, but this worked flawlessly on another java project, it's only in this android project where I get that issue. Maybe it could be a bug in my android's JVM?

Comment: There is only one solution of this problem is to put a null check.

Comment: The problem is not the null check, the problem is how am I supposed to retrieve the name with toString? I need the name not a null string.

Comment: Simply return `name` if not `null` and return an empty string if `name` is `null`. as edited it in my post.

Comment: I don't think you get this one, you may notice I'm pretty sure I set the `name` property before any call of the `toString` method but it either returns `null` or throws an exception with each approach respectively.

Comment: Have you tried it? may be internally a API method is calling `toString()` method and you don't aware of it. What the harm in putting a `null` check? Is it a big change?

Answer (score 1):

```
    return new String(name);
```

Would fail on name being `null`. It could happen on `A a = new A(); System.out.println(a):`.

The used constructor `String(String)` is a relict of the beginning of Java, reminiscent of the C++ copy constructor.

In Java String is immutable, and Java does not need the copy constructor.

Two solutions:

```
    return String.valueOf(name); // Would return "null" for null.
    return name == null ? "" : name;
```

Comment: Could you make it `private final String name;` and initialize it in the constructor. Extended my answer, something like `"" + a` already would invoke toString.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the exception goes you are getting a null pointer as already explained by @Kakarot.

**This line blows up**

```
original.count
```

But if you want to **save yourself from null checking etc** and at the same time have a **efficient** toString() method than user some thing like this.

```
   public class A {
        private String name = null;
        private String address = " Some place";

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            return sb.append(name).append(address).toString();
        }
    }
```

Using string builder is efficient and you can see the output for the above toString() even with null values.

```
null Some place
```

Comment: Okay, I can change the `return new String(name)` part to just `return name` but why do I get a null string? (when in fact I'm pretty sure I set it before calling it, as you may see on the added snippets).

Comment: @arielnmz I will suggest that make sure that getName() method is in fact accessing same property that is being used in toString() method as well. Also I see that you have a DataAccess.getAList() is a list of objects here. Have you verified all the objects in the list are okay and none of them have null names? Is somehow  state of the object changing between when you log the name and when it gets added to the list.